# If I upgrade my shop, does it increase the time of the goods' production?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Assuming I have 3 dream jobbers with level 9 skills each for a shop, if I were to upgrade the shop by a level, would it increase the production time of the 3 goods and by how much?

I read somewhere that upgrading a level would increase the numbers stocked by about 10%, but nothing about the time.

Trying to evaluate if it would be worthwhile to focus all my level-upgrading VIPs on 1 shop instead of spreading them around.

Comment: Upgrading can be effective in two ways.  One, upgrade a store with low stock levels so you don't have to restock as often.  Doesn't net as many credits, but improves game play.  Two, upgrade a big stocker, and you improve the haul from that store for no time penalty.  Depends upon your goal which is better.

Answer (score 1):

When you increase a shop's level, the number of stock is increased and the time selling is increased. **The time stocking does not increase.**  I have just verified this by upgrading one of my floors as well as [Alex](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/61697/alex) has confirmed this also.

Comment: I don't think that's true. I've never seen the ordering time go up, including just now when I upgraded Bounty Hunters from 4 to 5 and then to 6, and the 37 minute ordering for 650 units of carbonite freezing became 37 minute ordering for 750 units.

Comment: You are technically correct.  The best kind of correct.  I just verified this myself on one of my floors and updated the answer.  I was initially just going off of a previous posted answer on here!  grrr.  Thanks @Alex

Comment: @Zero Stack I've never seen it increase either, and I was convinced it did by the same bad post!